# Rolle's Theorem for functions defined on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

In J.Dieudonne's "Treatise on analysis, vol. 1" Chapter 8.2, there's a problem which asks to prove Rolle's theorem for a function defined on a Banach Space. The problem is as follows:

> Let f be a differentiable real-valued function defined in an open subset A of a Banach space E.
> a) Show that if at a point $x\in A$, f reaches a relative maximum, then $Df(x_0)= 0$.
> b) Suppose E is finite-dimensional, $A$ is relatively compact, $f$ is defined and continuous in $\bar{A}$, and equal to $0$ in the boundary of $A$. Show that there exists a point $x_0 \in A$ where $Df(x_0)= 0$.

I don't see where the necessity of $E$ being finite-dimensional comes in. Here's my proof:

Since $A$ is relatively compact, i.e. $\bar{A}$ is compact. Hence $f$ reaches its bounds on $\bar{A}$. If $f=const=0$ theorem is trivial. Assume then $f\neq const$. Wlog there is $y \in \bar{A}$ such that $f(y)>0$, for otherwise we can consider $-f$. Therefore there exists $x_0 \in \bar{A}$ such that $f(x_0)$ is the maximum of $f$ in $\bar{A}$. Since A is open its boundary is $fr(A) = \bar{A}\cap\bar{A'} = \bar{A}\cap A' = \bar{A} \setminus A$, hence $x_0 \in \bar{A}\setminus(\bar{A}\setminus A) = A$ since $A \subset \bar{A}$. Then $f$ has also a local maximum in $A$ at $x_0$, since for any neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $\bar{A}$ there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ contained in it and in $A$.Hence by a) $Df(x_0) = 0$.

What is wrong in that proof if $E$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: It's probably to avoid a vacuous question, because a normed space $E$ is finite dimensional if and only if the closed unit ball is compact (the implication $\implies$ follows 'easily' from say the theorem that all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent, and Heine-Borel. The reverse $\impliedby$ is more involved). Said differently, if $A\subset E$ is non-empty and open and has compact closure (so $\overline{A}$ contains a closed ball which must therefore be compact), then $E$ must be finite-dimensional.